# How to access my PC remotely without third party software?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, windows-server-2016

Let me describe my case, I have 5 PCs that located on other region. These PCs have access to the internet through Tp-link switch.So, I want to provide them support remotely without third party software. After surfing long time on internet, i found that static IP will solve my problem. I purchased one from my hosting company,then they assign it to a private DNS according to my requirement because I already have VPS. After that, I tried to assign The static IP to my PCs, for example:

Static IP : 1.2.3.43 PC1's IP: 1.2.3.44 Geteway : 1.2.3.43 Preferred DNS server : 1.2.3.43

When I save change the PC losing internet connection!.

Note: 1. I don't change router's IP, also router's DHCP is Enabled. 2. I use windows 10 pro in client. 3. VPS has windows server 2016

Could you please advise me what should I do? Thank you..

Comment: `Quick Assist` is built-in Windows 10.  Remote Desktop is built into both Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the static IP address to the router, not to the PCs. If they're under a router, they're in a local, private address range.

Once you've set a static IP to your router, you know that its IP will never change.

Now, the software you need to use for the remote desktop connection is **Windows Remote Desktop (WRD)**, which is built into Windows, as @Ramhound noted in his comment.
See [How to Set Up and Use Remote Desktop for Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/setup-use-remote-desktop-windows-10/).

Since your PCs are under a router, you'll have to use **ports** and **port forwarding**. An example of how to achieve that:

Assume `192.168.1.11`, `192.168.1.12`, and `192.168.1.13` are the three local IP addresses of the three PCs (for the sake of this example).

WRD uses port 3389. You need to open those ports for the three PCs.
In your router's Port Forwarding settings, forward 3 ports (of your choice) of your router to your PCs WRD service. For this example, I'll choose the ports `10001`, `10002`, and `10003` (for PC1, 2, and 3 respectively) to be the router's ports that we will forward to WRD.
Configure the following in the Port Forwarding section:
**From port**: 10001 **To destination IP**: 192.168.1.11 (PC 1) **To port**: 3389
**From port**: 10002 **To destination IP**: 192.168.1.12 (PC 2) **To port**: 3389
**From port**: 10003 **To destination IP**: 192.168.1.13 (PC 3) **To port**: 3389

And that's it.

Now to connect to your PCs remotely, from the **Windows Remote Desktop Client** simply enter the IP address and port for the PC you want to connect to. For example, if you want to connect to PC 2, you must enter `192.168.1.12:10002`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very clear. However, I asked my host company about usage of  the static IP that provided me, they said that you can not assign it to your router because it is a private IP.  It is really sad after paying 25$

Comment: Yeah, that is unlucky @user2697680. There's always the chance that your ISP's topology doesn't allow that and looks like that that is the case..